# Delphi SOAP Server exception unknown SOAP action

Tags: delphi, soap, webservicehost

I have to write a SOAP server to serve a given client. The client requests cannot be changed, so the server has to adapt to the client. IDE is Delphi XE2, the result is a standalone .exe. Its my first project in delphi, so please apologize if I missed some fundamentals.

The client requests a SOAP action e.g.

```
<soapenv:Body><login xmlns="http://my.name.space/MyService/"><username xmlns="">User</username><password xmlns="">pass</password></login></soapenv:Body>
```

The server throws an unknown soap action exception "http://my.name.space/MyService/login". The WSDL shows the SOAP action as

```
<operation name="login">
<operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" soapAction="http://my.name.space/MyService#login" style="rpc"/>
```

Is the '#' delimiter between namespace and method name causing the trouble? If it does, how can I tell delphi to use '#' as a delimiter when comparing the requested SOAP action? Or is it any other problem I'm running in?

Any help welcome!

Regards
Dieter

Comment: It's kind of late to answer this but the call you are receiving is in RPC format and not in SOAP format, that's why it's using **#** delimiter